# Angular 2 or 4 passing directive as @input to component html dynamically

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have created the text input field as component. Now i am using the component in a form multiple times. I want to apply a directive only to selected fields. I want to pass the directive name as the @input to component and pass it to component html template as attribute dynamically.

Psuedo code

```
<form> 

    <text-input-comp [directiveName]="mydirective" ></text-input-comp>
    <text-input-comp></text-input-comp>
    <text-input-comp></text-input-comp>

</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To apply directive to any element, you just need to call it as <text-input-comp mydirective ></text-input-comp>. I don't understand why you need to input for directive name?

Comment: <text-input-comp> is  my component selector name. my component looks like @Component({
  selector: 'aps-text-field',
  templateUrl: './text-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-field.component.scss']
}) . In text-field.component.html file has the actual html input field code. I want to apply directive to that html input field. @JayakrishnanGounder

Comment: Then apply directive to that input field directly. Share the html template for text-input-comp to help you